# integrate $(t\sin^2(t))dt$... why is my answer coming out wrong?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

I tried setting $u = t, dv = \sin^2t\mathrm{d}t$, then converting $dv$ to $1/2(1-\cos 2t)\mathrm{d}t$

with half angle identity,

Then $du = 1dt$ and $v = 1/2 - 1/4(\sin2t)$, then $$t\sin^2tdt = t(1/2 - 1/4 \sin2t) - (1/2 - 1/4 \sin2t)dt$$ then after evaluating I got $-(t\sin2t)/4 - (\cos2t)/8$
...

But the solutions manual says: $(1/4)t^2 -(t\sin2t)/4 - (\cos2t)/8$...

Did I miss a step?

Comment: Hint: you're first step absolutely should be to write $\sin^2(t) = \frac12 - \frac12 \cos (2t).$

Comment: i see. it just seems like the way i did it should still be legal...

Comment: It is legal. You just didn't appear to be having much success at it. Why use a rock when a pebble will do? ;)

Comment: but where did i mess up then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: We have:

$$\int t \sin^2 t ~ dt = \int \dfrac{1}{2} t(1 - \cos 2t)~dt = \dfrac{1}{2}\left(\int t~dt - \int t ~ \cos 2t ~ dt\right)$$

For the second integration, use integration by parts.

**Spoiler**

> $\dfrac{1}{8} \left( 2 t (t - \sin 2t) - \cos 2t \right) + c$

Comment: But "Don't Peek!" ;-) +1